# Which ports must be open on the server to use Logitech Media Server (LMS) for Squeezebox?

Tags: squeezebox

I have a Raspberry Pi running LMS to stream music to my different Logitech Squeezeboxes. Since I added UFW (uncomplicated firewall) to my Raspberry I needed to know which ports to open to use the logitechmediaserver/squeezeboxserver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer my own question since I had troubles finding **all** of the relevant ports.

**9000 TCP**: Web GUI

**9090 TCP**: CLI (for example used by Android app Squeezer)

**3483 TCP**: Physical Squeezebox

---

**31337**: I am not sure about this one. It seems to be a port for firmware updates from the server to the client and not necessary.

Comment: Your list (all for TCP, btw.) seems to agree with the output from `netstat` on my own server. In addition, there are a couple of ephemeral ports, but I don't think they are needed from the outside.

Comment: As I would like to have a comprehensive list here I would like you to share the additional ports.

Comment: No point in that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port

Comment: But most people would want to use the spotty plugin as well to support Spotify Connect. See my question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1786218/which-ports-must-be-open-on-the-server-to-use-the-spotty-plugin-spotify-connect