# Which ports must be open on the server to use the Spotty plugin (Spotify Connect) of a logitechmediaserver (lms)

Tags: spotify, squeezebox

In another topic ([Which ports must be open on the server to use Logitech Media Server (LMS) for Squeezebox?](https://superuser.com/questions/1442385/which-ports-must-be-open-on-the-server-to-use-logitech-media-server-lms-for-sq)) it was discussed which ports to open for a logitechmediaserver. But when I want to use it for Spotify Connect using the spotty plugin the firewall seems to block something. It might also be using multicast or broadcast ports.

It now only works when a spotify client is connected to the same account as the spotty plugin, but then it does the communication probably via the spotify servers on the internet. But with the firewall disabled anybody on my network can find the devices in the device manager. Anybody knows what to enable? I really need the firewall enabled as much as possible.

I've also created an issue to request for either fixing this or documenting this in the developers page of the plugin: https://github.com/michaelherger/librespot/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

Open port 4070 to make Spotty work.
https://github.com/michaelherger/Spotty-Plugin/issues/112

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).